# How to generate space between slices of pie chart in MDRotatingPieChart?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, pie-chart, ios-charts

I am using MDRotatingPieChart in my app and created a pie chart. I need space between the slices of pie chart. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can create demo project and provide downloadable URL here from dropbox or drive, so anyone can look into it and provide you solution.

Answer (score 6):

set `splicespace` on `piechartdataset`

```
pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Set slice space to piechart dataset

```
  var pieChartView: PieChartView!
  let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals:yourdataentries, label: "Units Sold")
    pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 5
  let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals:yourdatapoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through MDRotatingPieChart, they have developed very good, but unfortunately there is no provision to put space between slices.

Below are some option for solution.

(1) Put extra slice with value, color and label as "".

```
Data(myValue: 10.0, myColor: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1), myLabel:""),
```

[image]

(2) Use other libraries like - https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/104

You can download working example

[Download code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKZzNKVnQ2Wl9DVWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Well i have tried this code. This create space between slices.

let slice = createSlice(currentStartAngle - 0.015, end: CGFloat(currentStartAngle - currentAngle) + 0.015, color:currentColor, label:currentLabel, value:currentValue, percent:100 * currentValue/total)

Comment: Is that helped you? then you could accept an answer. let me if you are still stuck in charts.